# Laravel ID generator package strange issue

Tags: laravel

Strange issue with [Laravel ID generator](https://github.com/haruncpi/laravel-id-generator). I want to add a custom ID field in my orders table and I have this boot method in the model:

```
public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->order_number = IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'orders', 'length' => 6, 'prefix' => date('y')]);
        });
    }
```

This works and creates IDs like this:

`210001, 210002, ... ,210010`

The problem is that as soon as the ID hits 210010, then it restarts from 210001. I opened an issue on projects GIThub page but I wonder if there is a workaround for this.

Comment: Read about `reset_on_prefix_change` on docs https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-custom-id-generator

Comment: Thanks the prefix change is off by default. That is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the package works on the table's ID field but you are using the custom field `order_number` and you did not pass it to generate function. Look at example 4 on the [Laravel ID generator doc](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-custom-id-generator)

Try this code

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::creating(function ($model) {
        $args = ['table' => 'orders', 'field' => 'order_number', 'length' => 6, 'prefix' => date('y')];
        $model->order_number = IdGenerator::generate($args);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello, As I already answered on the closed github ticket. This still not works. The generated IDs are the same. please check this comment: https://github.com/haruncpi/laravel-id-generator/issues/31